# How to use an onItemClickListener to expand a listView when clicked?

Tags: java, android

I am currently completing a piece of coursework whereby I need to parse an XML file using android and display its data in a useful format on an android phone.

I have used XmlPullParser and have successfully parsed the file into a listView.
 Here is the result: [image]

To improve the layout above I have set the program to display the title alone (i.e. A78 Seamill etc) and when the user clicks on the title I would like info relating to the works to appear as a drop down.

In my MainActivity.java class I have a setOnItemClickListener that looks like the following:

```
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long title) {

            item.setExpand(true);


        }
    });
```

I also have a toString method in my Item.java class that looks like:

```
  @Override
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    if (getExpand() == true) {
        s = title + "\n" + description + "\n" + link + "\n" + georsspoint + "\n" + pubDate;
    } else if (getExpand() == false) {
        s = title;
    }
    return s;
}
```

I was hoping that when my onItemClickListener set the boolean "expand" to true my toString method would return the additional info.

I know the first piece of advice would be to use an expandableListView. I have already tried this and unfortunately it did not work due to the way in which I was retrieving my data:

```
List<Item> items = null;
    try {
        XmlPullParserHandler parser = new XmlPullParserHandler();
        items = parser.parse(getAssets().open("data.xml"));
        ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,R.layout.list_item, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated?
Thank you in advance

Regards
Patrick

Update:
There is no ArrayAdapter class as such but my full XmlParserHandler class may be if use to show you how the xml is parsed:

```
package com.example.traffic2;


import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Patrick Lafferty on 26/02/2018.
 */



public class XmlPullParserHandler {

List<Item> items;
private Item item;
private String text;



public XmlPullParserHandler() {
    items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}

public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}


public List<Item> parse(InputStream is) {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
    XmlPullParser parser = null;
    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        parser = factory.newPullParser();

        parser.setInput(is, null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        // create a new instance of item
                        item = new Item();

                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        // add employee object to list
                        items.add(item);

                    }else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                            item.setTitle(text);

                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                        item.setDescription(text);

                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        item.setLink(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("pubData")) {
                        item.setPubDate(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("georsspoint")) {
                        item.setGeorsspoint(text);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return items;
}

}
```

Update 2 = Please see item.java class below:

```
package com.example.traffic2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Patrick Lafferty on 01/03/2018.
 */

public class Item {

private String title;
private String description;
private String link;
private String georsspoint;
private String pubDate;
private boolean expand = false;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getGeorsspoint() {
    return georsspoint;
}

public void setGeorsspoint(String georsspoint) {
    this.georsspoint = georsspoint;
}

public String getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}

public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}


public boolean getExpand() {
    if (expand == false) {
        return expand = false;
    } else {
        return expand = true;
    }
}

public void setExpand(boolean expand) {
    this.expand = expand;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    if (getExpand() == true) {
        s = title + "\n" + description + "\n" + link + "\n" + georsspoint + "\n" + pubDate;
    } else if (getExpand() == false) {
        s = title;
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you look at ExpandableListView  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html ?

Comment: @Jimmy I have looked at the page you provided before coding a simple expandableListView from an online tutorial. Unfortunately the example project hard coded the arraylist child and parent which caused problems when I tried to apply my problem to its scenario.

Comment: @PatrickLafferty can you post your ArrayAdapter class?

Comment: @AungSiMinHtet I don't have an ArrayAdapter class as such but I do have a XmlPullParserHandler class. I hope my update helps. Thanks

Comment: Then can you post your Item.class? After that I can give you an advice for sure.

Comment: @AungSiMinHtet the item.java class has now been added.

Comment: @PatrickLafferty I have suggested my answer bro. Please give a try.

Comment: Thank you @AungSiMinHtet I will gave this ago tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Item.java, you implemented toString() methods and in that toString(), you check to expend the text or not.

The only thing you are missing is to refresh the list adapter after setExpand() is being called. To refresh the list adapter, you need to call notifyDataSetChanged().

```
final ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,R.layout.list_item, items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long title) {

        items.get(position).setExpand(true);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
```

Comment: For all having the same issue above - please note that this works. Also make sure you don't miss out items.get(position) so the onClickListener knows which item you are talking about. @AungSiMinHtet you are a genius - I was really struggling with this.

Comment: It's my great pleasure to know this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You should use a RecyclerView instead of a ListView. Then you will have ItemAnimator available to handle the insertion animations. Then all you have to do is call notifyItemInserted to produce the desired effect.

Tutorial:
http://frogermcs.github.io/recyclerview-animations-androiddevsummit-write-up/